# calculate the total price of two tables Mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables. The first table is called detail and the second table is called services.

First table: detail

[image: First Table]

Second table: services

[image: second]

Both are related through the `id_service`. 
What would be the query in Mysql to calculate the price of `'precio'`?

Comment: Do you want the price for a specific detail row? Or an aggregate price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the sum you could just use the services table, but if you want to group by a field or if you want to project the results of the details table you could [join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) the two tables and get the sum and project any other fields you might want in the select as below.

```
SELECT SUM(d.precio) as 'total' 
FROM detail d INNER JOIN
services s ON
d.id_servicio = s.id_servicio
```